# Why does MSVC's transparent operator functor implementation static_cast types to themselves?

Tags: visual-c++, stl

I was poking around the MSVC implementation of transparent operator functors (Visual Studio 2015), and noticed that all the specializations `static_cast` everything:

```
    // TEMPLATE STRUCT SPECIALIZATION less
template<>
    struct less<void>
    {   // transparent functor for operator<
    typedef _Is_trans is_transparent;

    template<class _Ty1,
        class _Ty2>
        _CONST_FUN auto operator()(_Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) const
        -> decltype(static_cast<_Ty1&&>(_Left)
            < static_cast<_Ty2&&>(_Right))
        {   // transparently apply operator< to operands
        return (static_cast<_Ty1&&>(_Left)
            < static_cast<_Ty2&&>(_Right));
        }
    };
```

...Why `static_cast` `_Right` to `_Ty2&&`, when it already is of type `_Ty2&&`? That seems totally redundant!

Comment: `static_cast<_Ty1&&>(_Left)` is the same thing as `std::forward<_Ty1>(_Left)`, just spelled out in full. As to why `std::forward` is needed for perfect forwarding, see e.g. [this](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)

Comment: Ahh, I remember it all now. It'd been a while since I used "forwarding references" of any sort, and that corner of the language got a bit dusty in my mind. Post that as an answer, and I'll accept it.